# Has Anyone Successfully Used CMU Sphinx for Programming by Voice Recognition

Tags: workflow, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I want to start doing some of my coding by voice recognition software (maybe 10-20% of the work I do).

I've seen that some people have had success with Dragon Natural Speaking (DNS) software, but I use a Mac, and unfortunately, Dragon only works on Windows.

Has anyone used the Carnegie Melon open source Sphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/ for programming?

Are there other options that I could implement on a Mac? I don't mind dropping a little bit of cash to make this a reality. Ideally it would be a system where I could add in my own commands. (Check out the awesome stuff this guy did, with DNS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI)

Comment: The answer is 'yes', there is even a bit messy [project about that on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/voicekey/). If done properly with speaker adaptation CMUSphinx can be extremely accurate and helpful. But StackOverflow is probably not the best place to discuss such an open-ended question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [protoype](https://github.com/breandan/idear) plugin for IDEA written by JetBrains developers. The work was done during one of their hackathons.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not fixed with Sphinx, I would recommend **[Kaldi](https://kaldi-asr.org/)** as an adaptable, compatible open-source speech recognizer. With kaldi you can adapt your own grammar and commands and retrain the underlying models. In addition, there is a [python-wrapper](https://github.com/gooofy/py-kaldi-asr) that makes Kaldis use easy and convenient.